# How to get D3D11 INFO: directx debug layer data on surface RT?

Tags: windows-runtime, directx, winrt-xaml, direct3d, direct3d11

OK - I'll ask this question correctly this time!

I am debugging resource loss with the dx debug layer and can get create/destroy "D3D11 INFO:" messages when running on the desktop and simulator. But when I run on the Surface RT these INFO messages do not show up.

I am using the DX Control panel to point to the executable VS produced but of course the executable is not running from that location - but perhaps that is the crux of the issue?

Has anyone seen these messages coming out or know what you need to do to get them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running a debug build? Does `SdkLayersAvailable()` (a method in the standard XAML+DX project template) return `true`?

Comment: Are you using the [`ID3D11InfoQueue::GetMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476549.aspx) API?

Comment: @Filip. I'm not doing anything different from the x86 build. I don't have access to the device here at home but I'll make the call to SdkLayersAvailable() later and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out which way you are normally getting these messages and rule out the basics I know of that could prevent them from showing.

Comment: I'd also make sure to ask the question in [DirectX MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/home?forum=wingameswithdirectx) which are more actively monitored by the members of the DirectX team.

Comment: @Flip. Sorry about the delay. Other things came up. SdkLayersAvailable() returns true. I also pointed the directX control panel to the executable across the network to the device exe path itself. Still no INFO messages. M thoughts now are there is no DX control panel for the Surface RT (that I can find and I have looked) and because of that there seems to be no way of turning the debug layer on.

I am turning the layer by setting the debug flag in the create call and using the dx control panel to add the exe to its list of apps that it will activate debug for. Again, all works under x86.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to help you. Maybe it's not (easily) available or maybe you'd need to listen to the messages in your code itself instead of relying on DX control panel or VS to relay them. Other than that - I'd check MSDN forums - there might be more knowledgeable people over there.